# Change whole image on rollover of imagemapped links

Tags: html, css, image, imagemap, rollover

I will try to explain this the best I can. I would like for each of these three Polaroids to have their own link, which I can do using an image map. My question is whether I can get the whole image to change upon each rollover so that the picture the mouse is hovering over becomes the foremost picture.

In other words, if I were to hover my mouse over the second photo, I would like that photo to then be on the top of the pile. I have created 3 versions of this image, all having a different order so that I can use it as a rollover image.

If this cannot be done using an image map, can someone suggest an alternate method?

Thanks.

image: [image]

Alternatively, can I darken the polygons upon hover in a way to hint that each one is a link?

Comment: Why not just use individual images and use CSS to adjust their z-index on hover?

Comment: That is actually a good idea. i am still new at this and have never used z-indexing, but i can figure it out. Thank you for the idea!